# Picking balls from a bag until there are three of same color

Tags: probability

A bag contains $20$ balls:

- $3$ Blue
- $4$ Purple
- $5$ Orange
- $8$ Green

You are allowed to pick balls until you have three the same colour  eg (3 - 9 picks ) No balls are replaced until a new round is begun. What is the probability of getting each colour on each round.

$3$ Blue,
$3$ Purple,
$3$ Orange,
$3$ Green.

---

Clarification: Each "round" you pick until you have three the same, this can take of course between 3 - 9 picks. From picking three the same in three picks to picking 2 the same during your first 8 picks in any order and the 9th would give you a 3 of a kind. I want to work out the total expected probability for each round eg 5% chance of blue 10% purple 25% orange 60% green If someone can help work out one colour I should be able to do the other 3.

I seem to be struggling  with the fact that, until the $3$rd ball, the order isn't important.

What I did for 1 of the 27 ways of getting blue for example was
$$\frac{\binom{3}{3}\binom{4}{2}\binom{5}{2}\binom{8}{2}}{\binom{20}{9} \binom{9}{1}} = 0.001111376$$

Comment: Show your struggle.

Comment: what I did for 1 of the 27 ways of getting blue for example was  =COMBIN(3,3)*COMBIN(4,2)*COMBIN(5,2)*COMBIN(8,2)/COMBIN(20,9)/COMBIN(9,1)  = 0.001111376

Comment: So are you asking for four separate probabilities?  Basically, the probability of drawing three of a particular color before drawing three of any other color, calculated separately for each color?

Comment: Yes each "round"  you pick until you have three the same, this can take of course between 3 - 9 picks. From picking three the same in three picks to  picking 2 the same during your first 8 picks in any order and the 9th would give you a 3 of a kind. I want to work out the total expected probability for each round  eg  5% chance of  blue  10%  purple  25% orange  60%  green   If someone can help work out one colour I should be able to do the other 3   Regards, and thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a more elegant way than this, but here's one way.

First, write down all of the color distributions that are not terminating, but could terminate on the next draw.  This means that you need to have drawn at least one color twice.  I'll designate the colors $1-4$ and not worry about order:

- $2$ balls:  $11$
- $3$ balls:  $112$
- $4$ balls:  $1122, 1123$
- $5$ balls:  $11223, 11234$
- $6$ balls:  $112233, 112234$
- $7$ balls:  $1122334$
- $8$ balls:  $11223344$

Next, for each of these color distributions, calculate the number of ways to arrange the digits.  This can be done with [multinomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).  For example, the number of ways to arrange $11223$ is
$$\frac{5!}{2!2!1!} = 30.$$

Next, observe that, for a given set of colors, the probability of drawing those colors is independent of the order.  For example,

$$BBGGP = \frac{3}{20} \frac{2}{19} \frac{8}{18} \frac{7}{17} \frac{4}{16},$$

but

$$PGBGB = \frac{4}{20} \frac{8}{19} \frac{3}{18} \frac{7}{17} \frac{2}{16},$$

which is exactly the same value.  All that happened was that the numerators got rearranged.

Now comes the somewhat tedious part, which is to calculate the individual probabilities for each substitution of colors.  We can at least be a little smart about it, and calculate the numerator part for each color:

$$B = 3, BB = 6, P = 4, PP = 12, O = 5, OO=20, G = 8, GG = 56.$$

Let's do the case for drawing three blue balls, and drawing the blue on the fifth ball.  We assign $BB$ to $11$ in the combination, and then write down all the others:  $$BBPP, BBOO, BBGG, BBPO, BBPG, BBOG.$$

(The first three are $1122$ types, and the last three are $1123$ types.)

To calculate the probability of getting each one of these, we multiply the probability of getting them in the stated order with the number of ways to rearrange them.  So,

$$P(BBPP) = \frac{6 \cdot 12}{20 \cdot 19 \cdot 18 \cdot 17}\cdot \frac{4!}{2!2!}.$$

Now, to find the probability of ending on the next turn with blue, given that you have two blues and two purples (drawn in any order), multiply by $1/16$.

**Then it's just a lot of rinse/repeat.** Do the same calculation for the rest of the four-ball colors.  Then do *all* of the other numbers of balls, for *all* of the applicable color combinations each time.

And that's just the first part of a four-part problem!

You can possibly reuse some of the calculations you did before if you keep track.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you keep picking until the very end.

How many distinct ways are there to extract all of the balls?   It is $\frac{20!}{3!\,4!\,5!\,8!}\;$; can you see why?

Now, how many of these distinct arrangements result in reaching the third **blue** before a third ball of any other colour?   That is how many have 2 blue and *no more* than 2 of each of the other colours before the third blue, and the rest after?

Divide the later by the former to obtain the probability that you will pick out three **blue** balls before you have three balls of any other colour.

---

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(\text{Blue}) & = 
\dfrac{
\sum\limits_{p=0}^2 \sum\limits_{o=0}^2 \sum\limits_{g=0}^2 
\dfrac{(2+p+o+g)!}{2!\,p!\,o!\,g!}\dfrac{(17-p-o-g)!}{0!\,(4-p)!\,(5-o)!\,(8-g)!}
}{
\dfrac{20!}{3!\,4!\,5!\,8!}
}
\\[1ex] & = \dfrac{42607}{1175720}
\end{align}$$

Can you do the rest?

---

Consider a simpler example: 4 red and 4 blue marbles in a bag.

There are $\frac {8!}{4!\,4!}$ distinct and equi-probable ways to extract all these marbles from the bag.

- There are $\frac{2!}{2!}\frac{5!}{1!4!}$ arrangement that have no red marbles before the third blue marble.
- There are $\frac{3!}{2!1!}\frac{4!}{1!3!}$ arrangements that have one red marble before the third blue marble.
- There are $\frac{4!}{2!2!}\frac{3!}{1!2!}$ arrangements that have two red marbles before the third blue marble.

Hence the probability of drawing three blue marbles before three red marbles is:

$$\cfrac{\cfrac{2!}{2!}\cfrac{5!}{1!4!}+\cfrac{3!}{2!1!}\cfrac{4!}{1!3!}+\cfrac{4!}{2!2!}\cfrac{3!}{1!2!}}{\cfrac {8!}{4!\,4!}} = \dfrac 1 2$$

Comment: Thanks for your input, however I am struggling with what your really asking me due to the fact that as you pick randomly you don't know how many picks its going to take before you have picked three the same eg 3 - 9 picks  on 9 picks for example there is  167,970  combinations of getting to the 9th ball. However for my problem I can eliminate most of those and only work out the 104 I need to ?  As I in theory only need to work out the total possible outcomes?  What am I missing as im getting more confused the more ways im trying  lol

Comment: @Steve to reach the third blue ball before a third ball of any other colour you need to pick, 2 blue balls, 0,1,or 2 purple balls, 0,1,or 2 orange balls, and 0,1,or 2 green balls before the third ball; leaving the remainder of balls (0 blue, 2,3,or 4 purple, 3,4,or 5 orange, 6,7,or 8 green).  Just calculate the probability of each of these 27 cases.

Comment: Hi,  shouldnt that be 1 blue?  But Many thanks for your answer and help, but I have now realised that this is clearly beyond my math skills :( and I wont be able to work it out myself as I don't even understand the equation that you showed above giving you the 42607/1175720 Luckily it was just something I saw and wanted to work out and not anything I needed to master!  Im still very annoyed I cant do it tho but that's life!

Comment: @Steve You need 2 blue among the balls before the third blue ball, none among those after.

Answer (score -2):

Hint:

Since you are drawing without replacement, you can imagine picking all the balls in order. You want the probability that the last three are all a particular colour.

By symmetry, this is the same as the probability that the first three are all that particular colour, an easier calculation I will leave for you.

Comment: What I did so far was worked out that there is 104 actual outcomes that im interested in.  27 for each of the colours. = 104   Im not sure I understand  that its the same probability that the first 3 are a particular colour and believe that is incorrect way to work it out as that   is  3/20 x 2/19 x 1/18  ?  0.000877193

Comment: Your expression is in fact correct for $3$ Blues.  But $3$ Greens are more likely to come together as there are more of them.

Comment: Im not sure if you understand the "rules"  you do not need 3 the same in order, only as a final result  eg   if you  pick  GOPPOGG  its the same as  GGOPOPG   = GREEN     Regards and thanks for your input so far.

Comment: OK, to restate what I said, your expression is in fact correct for $3$ Blues as the final three balls. But 3 Greens are more likely to be the final $3$ balls as there are more of them to start with.

Comment: Do you also agree with my logic that there is 27 ways to achieve each colour?  then 27 x 4 ?

Comment: No - I do not see where $27$ (presumably $3 \times 3 \times 3$) fits in.  For Blue you are interested in $3 \times 2 \times 1$ possibilities for the final three balls since when you have one you cannot have it again in a "without replacement" analysis.  For Green you are interested in $8 \times 7 \times 6$ possibilities.

Comment: ok I will explain my reasoning each round  after picking 3 - 9 balls you will have either 3 blue, purple, orange or green. lets say you got  3 blue. there is 27 ways to get this ?  3 blues + 27 combinations of the other 3 colours  eg  0,1,or 2 of each of the other colours. So I am trying to work out each of these 104 outcomes to give me the overall probability of each to total  1  Am I barking up the wrong tree?  Regards.

Comment: Perhaps I have misunderstood the original question.  You are drawing (presumably at random) from $20$ balls without replacement.  When do you stop drawing? I had read this as drawing $17$ balls and then looking to see if the $3$ remaining balls were all a particular colour.

Comment: Yes,  You pick 1 ball at a time randomly from the 20  and you only stop as soon as you have 3 the same colour, so between 3 picks and 9 would result in that event happening.  This is a far more complex problem than it first looks, hence my frustration lol   Technically the order don't matter, for example picking OOPBGPBGB  is the same  as  PPOGGOBBB   where blue was the end result. So I basically want to work out the overall probability of ending with  3 of each colour  for example  0.04  blue  0.17 purple  0.23 orange  and  0.56  =  1  for all

Comment: OK - this answer is for a different question.